# Is Wikipedia's inductive proof of the Binomial Theorem acceptable?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I thought [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) had a really elegant proof by induction of the binomial theorem. However, I wondered if the reasoning made at the line marked by (*) below is acceptable.

When $j = 0$, $k = n + 1$, so the left-hand side is the coefficient of the term $x^0y^{n + 1}$, but the right-hand side indicates that this coefficient is the sum of the coefficients of the terms $x^{-1}y^{n + 1}$ and $x^0y^n$, which doesn't seem to make sense. I would consider the case where $j = 0$ separately, which certainly turns out to be true, and only use the $(*)$ equality statement for $j \geq 1$, but I might be missing something. Please advise!

Thank you very much!

> When $n = 0$, both sides equal $1$, since $x^0 = 1$ and
> $\binom{0}{0}=1$. Now suppose that the equality holds for a given $n$;
> we will prove it for $n + 1$. For $j, k \geq 0$, let $[f(x, y)]_{j,k}$
> denote the coefficient of $x^jy^k$ in the polynomial $f(x, y)$. By the
> inductive hypothesis, $(x + y)^n$ is a polynomial in $x$ and $y$ such
> that $[(x + y)^n]_{j,k}$ is $\binom{n}{k}$ if $j + k = n$, and $0$
> otherwise. The identity
>
> $(x+y)^{n+1} = x(x+y)^n + y(x+y)^n$
>
> shows that $(x + y)^{n+1}$ is also a polynomial in $x$ and $y$, and
>
> $[(x+y)^{n+1}]_{j,k} = [(x+y)^n]_{j-1,k} + [(x+y)^n]_{j,k-1}$   $\quad\quad\quad\quad (*)$
>
> since if $j + k = n + 1$, then $(j - 1) + k = n$ and $j + (k - 1) =
> > n$. Now, the right hand side is
>
> $\binom{n}{k} + \binom{n}{k-1} = \binom{n+1}{k},$
>
> by Pascal's identity. On the other hand, if $j + k \neq n + 1$, then
> $(j - 1) + k \neq n$ and $j + (k - 1) \neq n$, so we get $0 + 0 = 0$.
> Thus
>
> $(x+y)^{n+1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{k} x^{n+1-k} y^k,$
>
> which is the inductive hypothesis with $n + 1$ substituted for $n$ and
> so completes the inductive step.

Comment: It does make sense; it's just that in the $j=0$ case one of the two summed coefficients is $0$.

Comment: @J.G. Hi, thank you. I assume you mean the coefficient of $x^{-1}y^{n + 1}$ is $0$? If so, I struggled to see how we could establish that. The inductive hypothesis says the coefficient is only $0$ if the sum of the exponents of $x$ and $y$ does not equal the exponent of the expression, but $-1 + (n + 1) = n$ does equal the exponent of $(x + y)^n$. Please advise!

Comment: That's not what it says. It says if $j+k\ne n$ the contribution is $0$, whereas if $j+k=n$ it's $\binom{n}{k}$, which is $0$ anyway if $k<0$ (a size-$n$ set has $0$ subsets of any negative size).

Comment: @J.G. Ah I see it now! It still bothers me a bit though using $j = -1$ as the original phrasing makes it sound like the expression $[f(x, y)]_{j,k}$ is only defined for $j, k \geq 0$, so it is more natural to me to interpret "otherwise" inside the context of $j,k \geq 0$. Do you think there is any problem in defining $j, k$ as integers only and proceeding that $\binom{n}{k}$ if $j + k = n$, and $0$ if $j + k \neq n$?

Comment: I think what _would_ be a problem is if we didn't insist on $j,\,k$ being integers. But it makes sense to have a symbol for the $x^{-1}y^{n+1}$ coefficient, even though it's $0$. At some point any inductive proof of this result has to choose to write either a sum of two possibly zero-valued terms or an expression that could be one term or two terms' sum. The latter approach is more confusing to try to express in algebra.